# Magento2: How to show tax rules for logged users?

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation

Magento 2.x

Now, Tax rules are showing guest and logged users. But I want to show only logged users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some backend Configuration. 
1. Create a different customer tax class for " Not logged in" customer group
and link with the same customer group
[image]

Store => Tax rule => Advance setting => Add Customer Tax Class
2. Customer => Customer group => Change tax class for Not logged In Customer Group
[image]

3. Create a Tax Rule=> Advance setting => select the customer tax class of general customer group. 
   [image]

4.Go to Store=> Confugration=> sale => Tax=> Price display setting=> Change it to including tax.
[image]

Guest
[image]

Logged In
[image]

More tax setup information you can refer this link:
https://www.twojay.co/blog/2018/7/16/tax-vat-configuration-magento2

Comment: Hi, Customer group option not getting me. @chandni Sachdev

Comment: Is it default function in Magento2? @chandni Sachdev

Comment: Yes, this is default Magento Functionality.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using @masud shaikh

Comment: Magento 2.0.17 I am using.

Comment: Yes i am getting option

Comment: When I select Guest class got the error - code is a required field.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/jo1T39

Comment: When I select the option and save got the error and Group name removed

Comment: Hi,  Can you tell me what is the issue? @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: I have checked with 2.1.8 and 2.2.5, I didn't get any issue. So am not sure why you are getting this issue

Comment: Ok...We are working on local server @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: It doesn't matter. are you using any 3rd party module? @MasudShaikh

Comment: Not tax-related any 3rd party module. @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: But I am using 3rd party FedEx extesion.

Comment: I guess FedEx is for shipping. Any module related to Customers?

Comment: Registration Extesion is also using 3rd party @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: Any option can we select from database? @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: I would suggest you disable that module and then try to save the Customer group

Comment: I have the disabled module but same issue. But I have changed class for General to set Guest is working. Only not worked for Not Logged In Group. @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: Okay that will also work, Now Set the customer tax class as Guest in your Tax rule

Comment: Ok, I will check tax rules apply or not for Not logged in user.

Comment: My senario Tax rules not apply to Guest. Taxt Apply only for Logged user. @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: Yes, Correct @MasudShaikh

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you so much @Chandni Sachdev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81586/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-chandni-sachdev).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81623/discussion-on-answer-by-chandni-sachdev-magento2-how-to-show-tax-rules-for-logg).

Comment: @MasudShaikh: For the issue, you are getting with not logged in customers because of changes in the database. I guess You did some changes in DB. So just delete that customer group and recreate it.